# How do I fit this table into a page? Using longtable

Tags: longtable

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lllll}
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Series ID} & \textbf{Tcode} & \textbf{Source} \endfirsthead 
\hline
1 & Real GDP & GDP\_real\_m & 6 & Bloomberg \\
2 & Mining and quarrying; manufacturing; electricity, gas, steam and air
  conditioning supply & MAQM & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
3 & MIG - intermediate goods & MIGIG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
4 & MIG - capital goods & MIGCG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
5 & MIG - consumer goods & MIGCONG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
6 & MIG - durable consumer goods & MIGDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
7 & MIG - non-durable consumer goods & MIGNDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
8 & Mining and quarrying & MAQ & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
9 & Manufacturing & MANF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
10 & Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply & EGSA & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
11 & PMI Manufactures & PMIM & 1 & BDSICE \\
12 & PMI Services & PMISER & 1 & BDSICE \\
13 & PMI Composite indicator & MPICOM & 1 & BDSICE \\
14 & Construction & CST & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
15 & Buildings & BLD & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
16 & Civil engineering works & CEW & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
17 & Wholesale and retail trade & WTR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
18 & Retail sale of food, beverages and tobacco & RETF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
19 & Retail sale of non-food products (including fuel) & RETNF & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
20 & Services required by STS regulation (except section G) & SERV & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
21 & Accommodation and food service activities & ACCOM & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
22 & EA.INDU & EA.INDU & 1 & European Commission \\
23 & EA.SERV & EA.SERV & 1 & European Commission \\
24 & EA.RETA & EA.RETA & 1 & European Commission \\
25 & EA.BUIL & EA.BUIL & 1 & European Commission \\
26 & ~Car registration, New commercial
  vehicles & CAR & 5 & ECB DW \\
27 & EA.ESI & EA.ESI & 1 & European Commission \\
28 & Building Permits Office buildings & BPER & 5 & ECB DW \\
29 & New heavy commercial vehicles & NCOMV & 5 & ECB DW \\
30 & New light commercial vehicles & NLCOM & 5 & ECB DW \\
31 & ~New orders, domestic market,
  MANUFACTURING & NODM & 5 & ECB DW \\
32 & New orders, non-domestic market, MANUFACTURING & NOND & 5 & ECB DW \\
33 & ~New orders, total, MIG
  intermediate goods working on orders~ & ORDINT & 5 & ECB DW \\
34 & New orders, total, MIG - Capital goods & ORDCG & 5 & ECB DW \\
35 & New orders, total, MIG durable consumer goods working on orders & ORDDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
36 & New orders, total, MIG non-durable consumer goods working on orders~ & ORDNDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
37 & New orders, total, MIG consumer goods working on orders & NOCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
38 & New orders, total, MANUFACTURING, FOR NEW ORDERS~ & NOMAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
39 & Unemp Total & UNTOT & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
40 & Unemp Less than 25 years & UNYG & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
41 & Unemp From 25 to 74 years & UNOD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
42 & The Employment expectations indicator & EMP & 1 & EU Commission \\
43 & Car registration, New passenger car & CPAS & 5 & ECB DW \\
44 & CONS.EA.TOT.COF.BS.M & CCON & 1 & European Comission~ \\
45 & CONS.EA.TOT.12.BS.M & CCONF & 1 & European Comission~ \\
46 & Imports Intra EA & IMPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
47 & Exports Intra EA & EXPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
48 & Imports extra EA & IMPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
49 & Exports Extra EA & EXPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
50 & Building Permits All buildings & BPAB & 5 & ECB DW \\
51 & HICP - Actual rentals for housing & HICPR & 6 & ECB DW \\
52 & All-items HICP & HICP & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
53 & Food and non-alcoholic beverages & FNALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
54 & Alcoholic beverages, tobacco and narcotics & ALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
55 & Clothing and footwear & CLOF & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
56 & Housing, water, electricity, gas and other fuels & HSWT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
57 & Furnishings, household equipment and routine household maintenance & FHE & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
58 & Health & HLT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
59 & Transport & TPT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
60 & Communications & COMM & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
61 & Recreation and culture & RECCUL & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
62 & Education & EDUC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
63 & Restaurants and hotels & REST & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
64 & Miscellaneous goods and services & MISSC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
65 & ECB Commodity Price index, import weighted & COMMIND & 6 & ECB DW \\
66 & Producer Price Index, total, MINING AND QUARRYING & PPIMIN & 6 & ECB DW \\
67 & Producer Price Index, total, Water collection, treatment and supply & PPIWTR & 6 & ECB DW \\
68 & Producer Price Index, total, Total Industry (excluding construction) & PPITOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
69 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Capital Goods Industry & PPICG & 6 & ECB DW \\
70 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPIDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
71 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Non-durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPINDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
72 & Producer Price Index, total, Consumer goods industry & PPICONS & 6 & ECB DW \\
73 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Energy & PPITOTEN & 6 & ECB DW \\
74 & Base money, Euro~ & B & 5 & ECB DW \\
75 & Reserves & RR & 6 & ECB DW \\
76 & Currency in circulation & CINC & 5 & ECB DW \\
77 & Overnight deposits, Total & ODT & 5 & ECB DW \\
78 & Monetary aggregate M1 & M1 & 5 & ECB DW \\
79 & Deposits with agreed maturity, Up to two years & DEPAM & 5 & ECB DW \\
80 & Deposits redeemable at notice, Up to 3 months & DEPRN & 5 & ECB DW \\
81 & Monetary aggregate M2 & M2 & 5 & ECB DW \\
82 & Repurchase agreements excluding repos with central counterparties & REPO & 5 & ECB DW \\
83 & Money Market Funds shares/units & MMFS & 5 & ECB DW \\
84 & Monetary aggregate M3 & M3 & 5 & ECB DW \\
85 & Loans, MFIs to Non-MFIs & LOMFI & 5 & ECB DW \\
86 & Loans, MFIs to Private Economy~ & LOPE & 5 & ECB DW \\
87 & Loans, MFIs to Non-Financial corporations & LOCOMP & 5 & ECB DW \\
88 & Loans, MFIs to Financial corporations & LOFCOR & 5 & ECB DW \\
89 & Loans, MFIs to General Government~ & LOGG & 5 & ECB DW \\
90 & Loans, MFIs to Households and non-profit institutions serving
  households~ & LOHO & 5 & ECB DW \\
91 & Credit for consumption, Outstanding~ & CRDCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
92 & Lending for house purchase, Outstanding~ & LENMORT & 5 & ECB DW \\
93 & Other lending, Outstanding~ & LENOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
94 & Euro stoxx 50 & SX50 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
95 & STOXX Europe 600 & ST600 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
96 & STOXX Europe 600 Industrial Goods  Services~ & SX600IND & 5 & Bloomberg \\
97 & Stoxx 600 utilites & SX600UTS & 5 & Bloomberg \\
98 & Stoxx 600 Banks & SX600UBK & 5 & Bloomberg \\
99 & Stoxx 600 Oil and Gas & SX600OG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
100 & Stoxx 600 Financial & SX600FIN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
101 & Stoxx 50 Volatility Index & SX50VOL & 1 & Bloomberg \\
102 & MSCI capital goods eur index & MXEU0CG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
103 & MSCI Europe Industrials Index & MXEU0IN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
104 & New Composite Indicator of Systemic Stress (CISS) & NCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
105 & Stress subindice - Bond Market & BNDCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
106 & Systemic Stress Composite Indicator, Index & CISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
107 & Stress subindice - Equity Market~ & EQCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
108 & Stress subindice - Fin. Interm. & FINCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
109 & Stress subindice - Foreign Exchange Market~ & EXCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
110 & Stress subindice - Money Market~ & MMCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
111 & Day-to-day rate & DTD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
112 & 1-month rate & 1M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
113 & 3-month rate & 3M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
114 & 6-month rate & 6M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
115 & 12-month rate & 12M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
116 & 1Y EA GDP-W yield & 1YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
117 & 5Y EA GDP-W yield & 5YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
118 & 10Y EA GDP-W yield & 10YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
119 & Swiss franc & CHF & 5 & ECB DW \\
120 & Chinese yuan renminbi & YUAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
121 & UK pound sterling & GBP & 5 & ECB DW \\
122 & Japanese yen & JPY & 5 & ECB DW \\
123 & Russian rouble & RUB & 5 & ECB DW \\
124 & US dollar & USD & 5 & ECB DW \\
125 & Short shadow rate WUXIA & SSR & 1 & Wu and Xia (2016) - Atlanta FED \\
126 & Short shadow rate Krippner & SSR & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
127 & Effective Monetary Stimulus & EMS (Effective Monetary Stimulus) & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
128 & The main refinancing operations rate & MRO & 1 & ECB SDW \\
129 & Deposit facility rate & DFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
130 & Marginal lending facility rate & LFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
131 & Monetary policy balance sheet & MPBL & 5 & ECB SDW
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs an `xltabular` environment instead of a `longtable` environment. Its advantage over the `longtable` setup is that it lets you employ the `X` column type (usually provided by the `tabularx` environment). I suggest using the `X` column type for column 2, as it really needs automatic line wrapping.

The following screenshot shows the first few rows of the resulting 5-page table. Remark: If your document setup uses narrower margins than the LaTeX default, the table will occupy much less than 5 pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % for column 2
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % for columns 3 & 5
\newlength\mylenA
\settowidth\mylenA{GDP\_real\_m} % measure width of column 3
\newlength\mylenB
\settowidth\mylenB{EUROSTAT}     % measure width of column 5

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l L P{\mylenA} l P{\mylenB} @{}}
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Series ID} & \textbf{Tcode} & \textbf{Source} \\
\midrule 
\endhead 

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & Real GDP & GDP\_real\_m & 6 & Bloomberg \\
2 & Mining and quarrying; manufacturing; electricity, gas, steam and air
  conditioning supply & MAQM & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
3 & MIG - intermediate goods & MIGIG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
4 & MIG - capital goods & MIGCG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
5 & MIG - consumer goods & MIGCONG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
6 & MIG - durable consumer goods & MIGDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
7 & MIG - non-durable consumer goods & MIGNDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
8 & Mining and quarrying & MAQ & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
9 & Manufacturing & MANF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
10 & Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply & EGSA & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
11 & PMI Manufactures & PMIM & 1 & BDSICE \\
12 & PMI Services & PMISER & 1 & BDSICE \\
13 & PMI Composite indicator & MPICOM & 1 & BDSICE \\
14 & Construction & CST & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
15 & Buildings & BLD & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
16 & Civil engineering works & CEW & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
17 & Wholesale and retail trade & WTR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
18 & Retail sale of food, beverages and tobacco & RETF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
19 & Retail sale of non-food products (including fuel) & RETNF & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
20 & Services required by STS regulation (except section G) & SERV & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
21 & Accommodation and food service activities & ACCOM & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
22 & EA.INDU & EA.INDU & 1 & European Commission \\
23 & EA.SERV & EA.SERV & 1 & European Commission \\
24 & EA.RETA & EA.RETA & 1 & European Commission \\
25 & EA.BUIL & EA.BUIL & 1 & European Commission \\
26 & Car registration, New commercial
  vehicles & CAR & 5 & ECB DW \\
27 & EA.ESI & EA.ESI & 1 & European Commission \\
28 & Building Permits Office buildings & BPER & 5 & ECB DW \\
29 & New heavy commercial vehicles & NCOMV & 5 & ECB DW \\
30 & New light commercial vehicles & NLCOM & 5 & ECB DW \\
31 & New orders, domestic market,
  MANUFACTURING & NODM & 5 & ECB DW \\
32 & New orders, non-domestic market, MANUFACTURING & NOND & 5 & ECB DW \\
33 & New orders, total, MIG
  intermediate goods working on orders & ORDINT & 5 & ECB DW \\
34 & New orders, total, MIG - Capital goods & ORDCG & 5 & ECB DW \\
35 & New orders, total, MIG durable consumer goods working on orders & ORDDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
36 & New orders, total, MIG non-durable consumer goods working on orders & ORDNDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
37 & New orders, total, MIG consumer goods working on orders & NOCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
38 & New orders, total, MANUFACTURING, FOR NEW ORDERS & NOMAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
39 & Unemp Total & UNTOT & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
40 & Unemp Less than 25 years & UNYG & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
41 & Unemp From 25 to 74 years & UNOD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
42 & The Employment expectations indicator & EMP & 1 & EU Commission \\
43 & Car registration, New passenger car & CPAS & 5 & ECB DW \\
44 & CONS.EA.TOT.COF.BS.M & CCON & 1 & European Comission \\
45 & CONS.EA.TOT.12.BS.M & CCONF & 1 & European Comission \\
46 & Imports Intra EA & IMPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
47 & Exports Intra EA & EXPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
48 & Imports extra EA & IMPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
49 & Exports Extra EA & EXPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
50 & Building Permits All buildings & BPAB & 5 & ECB DW \\
51 & HICP - Actual rentals for housing & HICPR & 6 & ECB DW \\
52 & All-items HICP & HICP & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
53 & Food and non-alcoholic beverages & FNALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
54 & Alcoholic beverages, tobacco and narcotics & ALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
55 & Clothing and footwear & CLOF & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
56 & Housing, water, electricity, gas and other fuels & HSWT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
57 & Furnishings, household equipment and routine household maintenance & FHE & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
58 & Health & HLT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
59 & Transport & TPT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
60 & Communications & COMM & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
61 & Recreation and culture & RECCUL & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
62 & Education & EDUC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
63 & Restaurants and hotels & REST & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
64 & Miscellaneous goods and services & MISSC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
65 & ECB Commodity Price index, import weighted & COMMIND & 6 & ECB DW \\
66 & Producer Price Index, total, MINING AND QUARRYING & PPIMIN & 6 & ECB DW \\
67 & Producer Price Index, total, Water collection, treatment and supply & PPIWTR & 6 & ECB DW \\
68 & Producer Price Index, total, Total Industry (excluding construction) & PPITOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
69 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Capital Goods Industry & PPICG & 6 & ECB DW \\
70 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPIDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
71 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Non-durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPINDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
72 & Producer Price Index, total, Consumer goods industry & PPICONS & 6 & ECB DW \\
73 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Energy & PPITOTEN & 6 & ECB DW \\
74 & Base money, Euro & B & 5 & ECB DW \\
75 & Reserves & RR & 6 & ECB DW \\
76 & Currency in circulation & CINC & 5 & ECB DW \\
77 & Overnight deposits, Total & ODT & 5 & ECB DW \\
78 & Monetary aggregate M1 & M1 & 5 & ECB DW \\
79 & Deposits with agreed maturity, Up to two years & DEPAM & 5 & ECB DW \\
80 & Deposits redeemable at notice, Up to 3 months & DEPRN & 5 & ECB DW \\
81 & Monetary aggregate M2 & M2 & 5 & ECB DW \\
82 & Repurchase agreements excluding repos with central counterparties & REPO & 5 & ECB DW \\
83 & Money Market Funds shares/units & MMFS & 5 & ECB DW \\
84 & Monetary aggregate M3 & M3 & 5 & ECB DW \\
85 & Loans, MFIs to Non-MFIs & LOMFI & 5 & ECB DW \\
86 & Loans, MFIs to Private Economy & LOPE & 5 & ECB DW \\
87 & Loans, MFIs to Non-Financial corporations & LOCOMP & 5 & ECB DW \\
88 & Loans, MFIs to Financial corporations & LOFCOR & 5 & ECB DW \\
89 & Loans, MFIs to General Government & LOGG & 5 & ECB DW \\
90 & Loans, MFIs to Households and non-profit institutions serving
  households & LOHO & 5 & ECB DW \\
91 & Credit for consumption, Outstanding & CRDCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
92 & Lending for house purchase, Outstanding & LENMORT & 5 & ECB DW \\
93 & Other lending, Outstanding & LENOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
94 & Euro stoxx 50 & SX50 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
95 & STOXX Europe 600 & ST600 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
96 & STOXX Europe 600 Industrial Goods  Services & SX600IND & 5 & Bloomberg \\
97 & Stoxx 600 utilites & SX600UTS & 5 & Bloomberg \\
98 & Stoxx 600 Banks & SX600UBK & 5 & Bloomberg \\
99 & Stoxx 600 Oil and Gas & SX600OG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
100 & Stoxx 600 Financial & SX600FIN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
101 & Stoxx 50 Volatility Index & SX50VOL & 1 & Bloomberg \\
102 & MSCI capital goods eur index & MXEU0CG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
103 & MSCI Europe Industrials Index & MXEU0IN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
104 & New Composite Indicator of Systemic Stress (CISS) & NCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
105 & Stress subindice - Bond Market & BNDCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
106 & Systemic Stress Composite Indicator, Index & CISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
107 & Stress subindice - Equity Market & EQCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
108 & Stress subindice - Fin. Interm. & FINCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
109 & Stress subindice - Foreign Exchange Market & EXCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
110 & Stress subindice - Money Market & MMCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
111 & Day-to-day rate & DTD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
112 & 1-month rate & 1M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
113 & 3-month rate & 3M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
114 & 6-month rate & 6M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
115 & 12-month rate & 12M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
116 & 1Y EA GDP-W yield & 1YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
117 & 5Y EA GDP-W yield & 5YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
118 & 10Y EA GDP-W yield & 10YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
119 & Swiss franc & CHF & 5 & ECB DW \\
120 & Chinese yuan renminbi & YUAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
121 & UK pound sterling & GBP & 5 & ECB DW \\
122 & Japanese yen & JPY & 5 & ECB DW \\
123 & Russian rouble & RUB & 5 & ECB DW \\
124 & US dollar & USD & 5 & ECB DW \\
125 & Short shadow rate WUXIA & SSR & 1 & Wu and Xia (2016) - Atlanta FED \\
126 & Short shadow rate Krippner & SSR & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
127 & Effective Monetary Stimulus & EMS (Effective Monetary Stimulus) & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
128 & The main refinancing operations rate & MRO & 1 & ECB SDW \\
129 & Deposit facility rate & DFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
130 & Marginal lending facility rate & LFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
131 & Monetary policy balance sheet & MPBL & 5 & ECB SDW
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

you need to enable automatic line wrapping in columns 2, 3, and 5:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lp{12em} p{5em}lp{5em}}
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Series ID} & \textbf{Tcode} & \textbf{Source} \endfirsthead
\hline
1 & Real GDP & GDP\_real\_m & 6 & Bloomberg \\
2 & Mining and quarrying; manufacturing; electricity, gas, steam and air
  conditioning supply & MAQM & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
3 & MIG - intermediate goods & MIGIG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
4 & MIG - capital goods & MIGCG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
5 & MIG - consumer goods & MIGCONG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
6 & MIG - durable consumer goods & MIGDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
7 & MIG - non-durable consumer goods & MIGNDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
8 & Mining and quarrying & MAQ & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
9 & Manufacturing & MANF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
10 & Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply & EGSA & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
11 & PMI Manufactures & PMIM & 1 & BDSICE \\
12 & PMI Services & PMISER & 1 & BDSICE \\
13 & PMI Composite indicator & MPICOM & 1 & BDSICE \\
14 & Construction & CST & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
15 & Buildings & BLD & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
16 & Civil engineering works & CEW & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
17 & Wholesale and retail trade & WTR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
18 & Retail sale of food, beverages and tobacco & RETF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
19 & Retail sale of non-food products (including fuel) & RETNF & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
20 & Services required by STS regulation (except section G) & SERV & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
21 & Accommodation and food service activities & ACCOM & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
22 & EA.INDU & EA.INDU & 1 & European Commission \\
23 & EA.SERV & EA.SERV & 1 & European Commission \\
24 & EA.RETA & EA.RETA & 1 & European Commission \\
25 & EA.BUIL & EA.BUIL & 1 & European Commission \\
26 & ~Car registration, New commercial
  vehicles & CAR & 5 & ECB DW \\
27 & EA.ESI & EA.ESI & 1 & European Commission \\
28 & Building Permits Office buildings & BPER & 5 & ECB DW \\
29 & New heavy commercial vehicles & NCOMV & 5 & ECB DW \\
30 & New light commercial vehicles & NLCOM & 5 & ECB DW \\
31 & ~New orders, domestic market,
  MANUFACTURING & NODM & 5 & ECB DW \\
32 & New orders, non-domestic market, MANUFACTURING & NOND & 5 & ECB DW \\
33 & ~New orders, total, MIG
  intermediate goods working on orders~ & ORDINT & 5 & ECB DW \\
34 & New orders, total, MIG - Capital goods & ORDCG & 5 & ECB DW \\
35 & New orders, total, MIG durable consumer goods working on orders & ORDDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
36 & New orders, total, MIG non-durable consumer goods working on orders~ & ORDNDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
37 & New orders, total, MIG consumer goods working on orders & NOCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
38 & New orders, total, MANUFACTURING, FOR NEW ORDERS~ & NOMAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
39 & Unemp Total & UNTOT & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
40 & Unemp Less than 25 years & UNYG & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
41 & Unemp From 25 to 74 years & UNOD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
42 & The Employment expectations indicator & EMP & 1 & EU Commission \\
43 & Car registration, New passenger car & CPAS & 5 & ECB DW \\
44 & CONS.EA.TOT.COF.BS.M & CCON & 1 & European Comission~ \\
45 & CONS.EA.TOT.12.BS.M & CCONF & 1 & European Comission~ \\
46 & Imports Intra EA & IMPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
47 & Exports Intra EA & EXPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
48 & Imports extra EA & IMPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
49 & Exports Extra EA & EXPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
50 & Building Permits All buildings & BPAB & 5 & ECB DW \\
51 & HICP - Actual rentals for housing & HICPR & 6 & ECB DW \\
52 & All-items HICP & HICP & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
53 & Food and non-alcoholic beverages & FNALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
54 & Alcoholic beverages, tobacco and narcotics & ALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
55 & Clothing and footwear & CLOF & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
56 & Housing, water, electricity, gas and other fuels & HSWT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
57 & Furnishings, household equipment and routine household maintenance & FHE & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
58 & Health & HLT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
59 & Transport & TPT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
60 & Communications & COMM & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
61 & Recreation and culture & RECCUL & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
62 & Education & EDUC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
63 & Restaurants and hotels & REST & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
64 & Miscellaneous goods and services & MISSC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
65 & ECB Commodity Price index, import weighted & COMMIND & 6 & ECB DW \\
66 & Producer Price Index, total, MINING AND QUARRYING & PPIMIN & 6 & ECB DW \\
67 & Producer Price Index, total, Water collection, treatment and supply & PPIWTR & 6 & ECB DW \\
68 & Producer Price Index, total, Total Industry (excluding construction) & PPITOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
69 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Capital Goods Industry & PPICG & 6 & ECB DW \\
70 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPIDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
71 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Non-durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPINDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
72 & Producer Price Index, total, Consumer goods industry & PPICONS & 6 & ECB DW \\
73 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Energy & PPITOTEN & 6 & ECB DW \\
74 & Base money, Euro~ & B & 5 & ECB DW \\
75 & Reserves & RR & 6 & ECB DW \\
76 & Currency in circulation & CINC & 5 & ECB DW \\
77 & Overnight deposits, Total & ODT & 5 & ECB DW \\
78 & Monetary aggregate M1 & M1 & 5 & ECB DW \\
79 & Deposits with agreed maturity, Up to two years & DEPAM & 5 & ECB DW \\
80 & Deposits redeemable at notice, Up to 3 months & DEPRN & 5 & ECB DW \\
81 & Monetary aggregate M2 & M2 & 5 & ECB DW \\
82 & Repurchase agreements excluding repos with central counterparties & REPO & 5 & ECB DW \\
83 & Money Market Funds shares/units & MMFS & 5 & ECB DW \\
84 & Monetary aggregate M3 & M3 & 5 & ECB DW \\
85 & Loans, MFIs to Non-MFIs & LOMFI & 5 & ECB DW \\
86 & Loans, MFIs to Private Economy~ & LOPE & 5 & ECB DW \\
87 & Loans, MFIs to Non-Financial corporations & LOCOMP & 5 & ECB DW \\
88 & Loans, MFIs to Financial corporations & LOFCOR & 5 & ECB DW \\
89 & Loans, MFIs to General Government~ & LOGG & 5 & ECB DW \\
90 & Loans, MFIs to Households and non-profit institutions serving
  households~ & LOHO & 5 & ECB DW \\
91 & Credit for consumption, Outstanding~ & CRDCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
92 & Lending for house purchase, Outstanding~ & LENMORT & 5 & ECB DW \\
93 & Other lending, Outstanding~ & LENOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
94 & Euro stoxx 50 & SX50 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
95 & STOXX Europe 600 & ST600 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
96 & STOXX Europe 600 Industrial Goods  Services~ & SX600IND & 5 & Bloomberg \\
97 & Stoxx 600 utilites & SX600UTS & 5 & Bloomberg \\
98 & Stoxx 600 Banks & SX600UBK & 5 & Bloomberg \\
99 & Stoxx 600 Oil and Gas & SX600OG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
100 & Stoxx 600 Financial & SX600FIN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
101 & Stoxx 50 Volatility Index & SX50VOL & 1 & Bloomberg \\
102 & MSCI capital goods eur index & MXEU0CG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
103 & MSCI Europe Industrials Index & MXEU0IN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
104 & New Composite Indicator of Systemic Stress (CISS) & NCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
105 & Stress subindice - Bond Market & BNDCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
106 & Systemic Stress Composite Indicator, Index & CISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
107 & Stress subindice - Equity Market~ & EQCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
108 & Stress subindice - Fin. Interm. & FINCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
109 & Stress subindice - Foreign Exchange Market~ & EXCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
110 & Stress subindice - Money Market~ & MMCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
111 & Day-to-day rate & DTD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
112 & 1-month rate & 1M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
113 & 3-month rate & 3M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
114 & 6-month rate & 6M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
115 & 12-month rate & 12M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
116 & 1Y EA GDP-W yield & 1YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
117 & 5Y EA GDP-W yield & 5YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
118 & 10Y EA GDP-W yield & 10YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
119 & Swiss franc & CHF & 5 & ECB DW \\
120 & Chinese yuan renminbi & YUAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
121 & UK pound sterling & GBP & 5 & ECB DW \\
122 & Japanese yen & JPY & 5 & ECB DW \\
123 & Russian rouble & RUB & 5 & ECB DW \\
124 & US dollar & USD & 5 & ECB DW \\
125 & Short shadow rate WUXIA & SSR & 1 & Wu and Xia (2016) - Atlanta FED \\
126 & Short shadow rate Krippner & SSR & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
127 & Effective Monetary Stimulus & EMS (Effective Monetary Stimulus) & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
128 & The main refinancing operations rate & MRO & 1 & ECB SDW \\
129 & Deposit facility rate & DFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
130 & Marginal lending facility rate & LFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
131 & Monetary policy balance sheet & MPBL & 5 & ECB SDW
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

However, at writing your table, I would consider `xltabular` or `tabularray` packages.

**Addendum:**
You may consider

- to make text area wider by use of the `geometry` package
- to use table notes where you in table explain meaning of abbreviation(s)
- use of the `tabularray` packages in table design:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Caption text},
  label = {tab:long},
note{a} = {EFM: Effective Monetary Stimulus}
                ]{colsep=4pt,
                  colspec={@{} c X[2,l] l c X[1,l] @{}},
                  row{1}={font=\bfseries, c},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
No.    & Title  & Series ID & Tcode & Source    \\
    \midrule
1 & Real GDP & GDP\_real\_m & 6 & Bloomberg \\
2 & Mining and quarrying; manufacturing; electricity, gas, steam and air
  conditioning supply & MAQM & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
3 & MIG - intermediate goods & MIGIG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
4 & MIG - capital goods & MIGCG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
5 & MIG - consumer goods & MIGCONG & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
6 & MIG - durable consumer goods & MIGDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
7 & MIG - non-durable consumer goods & MIGNDUR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
8 & Mining and quarrying & MAQ & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
9 & Manufacturing & MANF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
10 & Electricity, gas, steam and air conditioning supply & EGSA & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
11 & PMI Manufactures & PMIM & 1 & BDSICE \\
12 & PMI Services & PMISER & 1 & BDSICE \\
13 & PMI Composite indicator & MPICOM & 1 & BDSICE \\
14 & Construction & CST & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
15 & Buildings & BLD & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
16 & Civil engineering works & CEW & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
17 & Wholesale and retail trade & WTR & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
18 & Retail sale of food, beverages and tobacco & RETF & 5 & EUROSTAT \\
19 & Retail sale of non-food products (including fuel) & RETNF & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
20 & Services required by STS regulation (except section G) & SERV & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
21 & Accommodation and food service activities & ACCOM & 2 & EUROSTAT \\
22 & EA.INDU & EA.INDU & 1 & European Commission \\
23 & EA.SERV & EA.SERV & 1 & European Commission \\
24 & EA.RETA & EA.RETA & 1 & European Commission \\
25 & EA.BUIL & EA.BUIL & 1 & European Commission \\
26 & ~Car registration, New commercial
  vehicles & CAR & 5 & ECB DW \\
27 & EA.ESI & EA.ESI & 1 & European Commission \\
28 & Building Permits Office buildings & BPER & 5 & ECB DW \\
29 & New heavy commercial vehicles & NCOMV & 5 & ECB DW \\
30 & New light commercial vehicles & NLCOM & 5 & ECB DW \\
31 & ~New orders, domestic market,
  MANUFACTURING & NODM & 5 & ECB DW \\
32 & New orders, non-domestic market, MANUFACTURING & NOND & 5 & ECB DW \\
33 & ~New orders, total, MIG
  intermediate goods working on orders~ & ORDINT & 5 & ECB DW \\
34 & New orders, total, MIG - Capital goods & ORDCG & 5 & ECB DW \\
35 & New orders, total, MIG durable consumer goods working on orders & ORDDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
36 & New orders, total, MIG non-durable consumer goods working on orders~ & ORDNDUR & 5 & ECB DW \\
37 & New orders, total, MIG consumer goods working on orders & NOCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
38 & New orders, total, MANUFACTURING, FOR NEW ORDERS~ & NOMAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
39 & Unemp Total & UNTOT & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
40 & Unemp Less than 25 years & UNYG & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
41 & Unemp From 25 to 74 years & UNOD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
42 & The Employment expectations indicator & EMP & 1 & EU Commission \\
43 & Car registration, New passenger car & CPAS & 5 & ECB DW \\
44 & CONS.EA.TOT.COF.BS.M & CCON & 1 & European Comission~ \\
45 & CONS.EA.TOT.12.BS.M & CCONF & 1 & European Comission~ \\
46 & Imports Intra EA & IMPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
47 & Exports Intra EA & EXPI & 5 & Eurostat \\
48 & Imports extra EA & IMPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
49 & Exports Extra EA & EXPE & 5 & Eurostat \\
50 & Building Permits All buildings & BPAB & 5 & ECB DW \\
51 & HICP - Actual rentals for housing & HICPR & 6 & ECB DW \\
52 & All-items HICP & HICP & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
53 & Food and non-alcoholic beverages & FNALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
54 & Alcoholic beverages, tobacco and narcotics & ALC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
55 & Clothing and footwear & CLOF & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
56 & Housing, water, electricity, gas and other fuels & HSWT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
57 & Furnishings, household equipment and routine household maintenance & FHE & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
58 & Health & HLT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
59 & Transport & TPT & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
60 & Communications & COMM & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
61 & Recreation and culture & RECCUL & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
62 & Education & EDUC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
63 & Restaurants and hotels & REST & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
64 & Miscellaneous goods and services & MISSC & 6 & EUROSTAT \\
65 & ECB Commodity Price index, import weighted & COMMIND & 6 & ECB DW \\
66 & Producer Price Index, total, MINING AND QUARRYING & PPIMIN & 6 & ECB DW \\
67 & Producer Price Index, total, Water collection, treatment and supply & PPIWTR & 6 & ECB DW \\
68 & Producer Price Index, total, Total Industry (excluding construction) & PPITOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
69 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Capital Goods Industry & PPICG & 6 & ECB DW \\
70 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPIDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
71 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Non-durable Consumer Goods Industry & PPINDUR & 6 & ECB DW \\
72 & Producer Price Index, total, Consumer goods industry & PPICONS & 6 & ECB DW \\
73 & Producer Price Index, total, MIG Energy & PPITOTEN & 6 & ECB DW \\
74 & Base money, Euro~ & B & 5 & ECB DW \\
75 & Reserves & RR & 6 & ECB DW \\
76 & Currency in circulation & CINC & 5 & ECB DW \\
77 & Overnight deposits, Total & ODT & 5 & ECB DW \\
78 & Monetary aggregate M1 & M1 & 5 & ECB DW \\
79 & Deposits with agreed maturity, Up to two years & DEPAM & 5 & ECB DW \\
80 & Deposits redeemable at notice, Up to 3 months & DEPRN & 5 & ECB DW \\
81 & Monetary aggregate M2 & M2 & 5 & ECB DW \\
82 & Repurchase agreements excluding repos with central counterparties & REPO & 5 & ECB DW \\
83 & Money Market Funds shares/units & MMFS & 5 & ECB DW \\
84 & Monetary aggregate M3 & M3 & 5 & ECB DW \\
85 & Loans, MFIs to Non-MFIs & LOMFI & 5 & ECB DW \\
86 & Loans, MFIs to Private Economy~ & LOPE & 5 & ECB DW \\
87 & Loans, MFIs to Non-Financial corporations & LOCOMP & 5 & ECB DW \\
88 & Loans, MFIs to Financial corporations & LOFCOR & 5 & ECB DW \\
89 & Loans, MFIs to General Government~ & LOGG & 5 & ECB DW \\
90 & Loans, MFIs to Households and non-profit institutions serving
  households~ & LOHO & 5 & ECB DW \\
91 & Credit for consumption, Outstanding~ & CRDCON & 5 & ECB DW \\
92 & Lending for house purchase, Outstanding~ & LENMORT & 5 & ECB DW \\
93 & Other lending, Outstanding~ & LENOT & 6 & ECB DW \\
94 & Euro stoxx 50 & SX50 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
95 & STOXX Europe 600 & ST600 & 5 & Bloomberg \\
96 & STOXX Europe 600 Industrial Goods  Services~ & SX600IND & 5 & Bloomberg \\
97 & Stoxx 600 utilites & SX600UTS & 5 & Bloomberg \\
98 & Stoxx 600 Banks & SX600UBK & 5 & Bloomberg \\
99 & Stoxx 600 Oil and Gas & SX600OG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
100 & Stoxx 600 Financial & SX600FIN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
101 & Stoxx 50 Volatility Index & SX50VOL & 1 & Bloomberg \\
102 & MSCI capital goods eur index & MXEU0CG & 5 & Bloomberg \\
103 & MSCI Europe Industrials Index & MXEU0IN & 5 & Bloomberg \\
104 & New Composite Indicator of Systemic Stress (CISS) & NCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
105 & Stress subindice - Bond Market & BNDCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
106 & Systemic Stress Composite Indicator, Index & CISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
107 & Stress subindice - Equity Market~ & EQCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
108 & Stress subindice - Fin. Interm. & FINCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
109 & Stress subindice - Foreign Exchange Market~ & EXCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
110 & Stress subindice - Money Market~ & MMCISS & 1 & Bloomberg \\
111 & Day-to-day rate & DTD & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
112 & 1-month rate & 1M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
113 & 3-month rate & 3M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
114 & 6-month rate & 6M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
115 & 12-month rate & 12M & 1 & EUROSTAT \\
116 & 1Y EA GDP-W yield & 1YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
117 & 5Y EA GDP-W yield & 5YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
118 & 10Y EA GDP-W yield & 10YGDPW & 1 & Bloomberg \\
119 & Swiss franc & CHF & 5 & ECB DW \\
120 & Chinese yuan renminbi & YUAN & 5 & ECB DW \\
121 & UK pound sterling & GBP & 5 & ECB DW \\
122 & Japanese yen & JPY & 5 & ECB DW \\
123 & Russian rouble & RUB & 5 & ECB DW \\
124 & US dollar & USD & 5 & ECB DW \\
125 & Short shadow rate WUXIA & SSR & 1 & Wu and Xia (2016) - Atlanta FED \\
126 & Short shadow rate Krippner & SSR & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
127 & Effective Monetary Stimulus & EMS\TblrNote{a} & 1 & Krippner (2013) \\
128 & The main refinancing operations rate & MRO & 1 & ECB SDW \\
129 & Deposit facility rate & DFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
130 & Marginal lending facility rate & LFR & 1 & ECB SDW \\
131 & Monetary policy balance sheet & MPBL & 5 & ECB SDW    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing the first paragraph of your posting.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! I'm on vacation now, and my brain on, for us  extremely hot. weather (34 degree C), have become very lazy ...